# What is the "correct" way to reconcile malloc and new in a mixed C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc, new-operator

I have a mixed C/C++ program.  It contains a flex/bison parser which targets C, while the remainder is C++.

Being C, the generated parser and scanner manage their memory with `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`.  They are good enough to expose hooks allowing me to submit my own implementations of these functions.  As you might expect, the rest of the (C++) program "wants" to use `new`, `delete`, etc.

Doing a little research seems to show that the relevant standards do not guarantee that such mixing should work.  Particularly the C "heap" is not necessarily the C++ "free area".  It seems the two schemes can trample each other.

On top of this, someday (soon) this program will probably want to integrate a customized heap implementation such as [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html), used by both C and C++.

**What is the "right" thing to do here?**

Given the desire to integrate tcmalloc (which explains how to link with C programs) I'm tempted to find some cross-type, cross-thread, cross-everything overload/hook/whatever into C++ memory management.  With that I could point all C++ allocation/release calls back to their C equivalents (which in turn land on tcmalloc.)

Does such a pan-galactic global C++ hook exist?  Might it already be doing what I want, similar to how `ios_base::sync_with_stdio` secretly marries iostream and stdio by default?

I am not interested in talking about stdio vs. iostreams, nor about switching parser generators nor using the C++ flex/bison skeletons (they introduce independent headaches.)

**EDIT**: Please include the names of those sections of the C++ standard that support your answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The standard *does* guarantee that mixing the two allocation variants will work. What it *doesn't* permit is things like calling `free` on memory that came from `new`, since they may use a totally different arena for the two types.

Providing you remember to call the correct deallocation function for a given block of memory, you will be fine. They *won't* trample each other if you follow the rules and, if you don't follow the rules then, technically, *you're* doing the trampling, not them :-)

---

The controlling part of the C++11 standard is `20.6.13 C library` which states, paraphrased:

- The functions `calloc`, `malloc`, `free` and `realloc` are provided, based on the C standard.
- The functions do not use `::operator new()` or `::operator delete()`.
- This allows the heritage C stuff to use a different memory arena then the normal C++ memory allocation.

That second bullet point is interesting in light of what you're eventually proposing, dropping in `tcmalloc` to replace the C heritage functions and have C++ use it as well.

There's a footnote in the standard which explains why they don't use let `malloc()` call `::operator new()`:

> The intent is to have operator new() implementable by calling std::malloc() or std::calloc(). In other words, they want to avoid a circular dependency.

However, while it *allows* `operator new()` to call `malloc()`, I'm not sure that the standard actually *requires* it. So, to be safe, you'd probably want to inject `tcmalloc` into both the C *and* C++ areas.

You've indicated you already know how to do that for C. For C++, it can be done by simply providing the entire set of global `operator new()/delete()` functions in your code, suitably written to call `tcmalloc` under the covers. The C++ standard states in `3.7.4 Dynamic storage duration`:

> The library provides default definitions for the global allocation and deallocation functions. Some global allocation and deallocation functions are replaceable.
>
> A C++ program shall provide at most one definition of a replaceable allocation or deallocation function. Any such function definition replaces the
>   default version provided in the library.
>
> The following allocation and deallocation functions are implicitly declared in global scope in each translation unit of a program:
>
> - `void* operator new(std::size_t);`
> - `void* operator new[](std::size_t);`
> - `void operator delete(void*);`
> - `void operator delete[](void*);`

Comment: Is that actually true?  I'm seeing a lot of mixed reports (and noise) googling around.  (for the record I understand to free mallocs and delete news, and I trust the generated parser to clean up after itself.)

Comment: Yes, it is true. I don't have the standard on my Android but I'll find the relevant section once I get to work if you like.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you.  Do you have any insight to the 2nd half of the question?  If I `LD_PRELOAD` `malloc`/`free` to new implementations, will those also affect C++ allocations?  Even if the standard is silent, pragmatically knowing the behavior of actual compilers would be very useful.

Comment: @phs - the standard versions of `operator new` and `operator delete` use `malloc` and `free` to get their memory. They aren't required to make a separate call for every allocation, but replacing `malloc` and `free` with custom versions will make the C++ code use the replaced versions. Well, unless you're deep in DLL hell.

Comment: I know it's been a while since you answered this, but if you have the time, could you try to find the relevant part of the spec? I'm curious to see it!

Comment: @templatetypedef, done, albeit with a pretty dismal response time :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  Dug up an old working draft of the standard (2/28/2011 rev 3242.)  It appears the relevant sections are `3.7.4 Dynamic storage duration` and `18.6.1 Storage allocation and deallocation`.

In short it seems the pan-galactic hook I wanted are the global new and delete operators themselves.  If one respects some semantics (in `3.7.4.1` and `3.7.4.2`: basically delegate to `new_handler` as needed) one is allowed to replace

```
void* operator new(std::size_t);
void* operator new[](std::size_t);
void operator delete(void*);
void operator delete[](void*);
```

to arrest default memory management of the entire C++ program.  I still can't find the section that proves @paxdiablo right, but I'm willing to run with it for now.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to worry about any memory allocated by the generated code of Flex or Bison; they take care of it themselves.  For the rest, just use `new` and `delete`.  (And Flex and Bison are capable of generating C++, of a sort.  In general, I've found running the output through a simple script, using `sed` has been sufficient to make their output truly C++ compatible.)