# How to use my own implementation for malloc, realloc and free inside bison+flex?

Tags: memory, bison, flex-lexer

I am using bison + flex to write a parser now.

For bison and flex, the generated parser and scanner manage their memory with malloc, realloc and free.

But I want to use my own implementation for malloc, realloc and free inside bison + flex.

According to another post:

> Being C, the generated parser and scanner manage their memory with `malloc`, `realloc` and `free`. They are good enough to expose hooks allowing me to submit my own implementations of these functions.

Where are those hooks and how do I use them?

Comment: The post you quoted is probably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674332/what-is-the-correct-way-to-reconcile-malloc-and-new-in-a-mixed-c-c-program), you should link to it.

Answer (score 0):

The flex overrides are described in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Overriding-The-Default-Memory-Management.html). In summary, you need to define the functions `yyalloc`, `yyfree` and `yyrealloc` (whose prototypes are unsurprising, but read the manual if you are using a reentrant scanner), and *also* tell flex not to generate the functions:

```
%option noyyalloc noyyfree noyyrealloc
```

For bison, if you are using the standard C skeleton, you can define the macros `YYMALLOC` and `YYFREE`, whose default values are `malloc` and `free`. bison does not (by default) use `realloc`. I presume this is not documented because it is dependent on the skeleton used.